# AJAX/JSON dynamic content load on page scroll issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, scrollbar

Currently trying to iterate through json objects, format HTML for object but then dynamically load each object as the user scrolls down the page, this is my current problem I iterate through the json objects, display them on page scroll, but when I scroll down It shows all objects when I want it to show each object and as the user scrolls down the page, shows more json objects.

HTML code

```
    <body>
     <div id='container'>
     <div id='content'>
     <article class='tumblrPost'>
     <header>
        <h1> Dragonball Z Motivation </h1>
    </header>
         <img src='images/dragonball_z.jpg' alt='dragonball z' title='dbz' />
    <footer>
            <h1> Watch the Video Life & Motivation with Dragonball Z </h1>
    </footer>
    </article>
        </div>
        </div>
        </body>
```

javascript code

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    var articlePosts = $('div#content article');
    $('div#content').children().first().css('display',  'block').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $('document').height() -   $('window').height()) {
         getPosts();
        }
    });
  }); 
      function getPosts() {
      var visiblePosts = $('div#content article:visible');
      $.getJSON('animeTest.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $(window).unbind('scroll');
        var output = $("<article class='tumblrPost'></article>");
        var header = $("<header></header>");
        header.append("<h1>" + val.header + "</h1>").appendTo(output);
        output.append("<img src='images/" + val.image + "' title='Image' />");
        var footer = $("<footer></footer>");
        footer.append("<h1>" + val.footer + "</h1>").appendTo(output);
        visiblePosts.last().after(output);
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= visiblePosts.last().offset().top - 100) {
        output.css('display', 'block').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
        }
    });     
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

each time when you call getPosts(); append an empty element tag (i.e End of Posts) with in article tag give an id for that element 
when the user scrolls the page 
and get the scrolltop position of that empty element tag and then again call getPosts(); and do the same...

Answer (score 0):

instead of using $('document').height() and $('window').height(), use 
$(document).height() and $(window).height(). Works perfectly with JQuery3.6.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     var limit=10;
     var offset = limit;
     $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() -  $(window).height()) {
           //alert("reached the bottom");
           $.post('ajax_handler.php',
                    {
                        offset: offset,
                        limit : limit,
                    },
                    function (data, status) {
                        if (status=="success"){
                                    $('#tbl_customers').append(data);
                                    offset+=limit;                      
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
    });             
    });
```